# Chrome cutting off icons from SVG sprite and gradients not working in Firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, svg

EDIT: Found the following solution:

Chrome had problems with the *defs* tags nested inside the *symbol* tag. So it did not render the contents inside those *defs* tags correctly. After cleaning up the files chrome is now displaying everything as it should.

Firefox can't display gradients if they are nested inside a *symbol* tag (as mentioned in the comments). Putting them outside of the *symbol* tag fixes this.

ORIGINAL POST:

Currently I am reworking a website, where for now every logo is loaded separately. To change this I am working with SVG sprites.

The Layout of the SVG file:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" display="none">
    <symbol id="logo_1" viewBox="icon-specific-viewbox">
        <!-- paths and stuff -->
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="logo_2" viewBox="icon-specific-viewbox">
        <!-- paths and stuff -->
    </symbol>
    <!-- much more icons -->
</svg>
```

In HTML I call them with:

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="#logo_1"></use>
</svg>
```

Everything so far is working fine, the icons appear where I want them to and they have the correct size.

EDIT: Here is a [Pen with simplified code](https://codepen.io/IIFLIPII/pen/vmgBGM). In my actual files, the viewBox differs in every symbol and is less straight forward.

Now to the problem:

As mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806913/how-can-i-refer-to-an-internal-gradient-definition-inside-an-svg-sprite-symbol), linear gradients are not working if the parent SVG element has *display="none"*. But when I now remove this property, the gradients are working in Chrome but not in Firefox. (You can test this in the Pen)

Adding to this, Chrome is cutting off some of the icons when *display="none"* is not set and I don't know how to fix this (Firefox is not cutting them off, they work just like they did in Chrome when I used *display="none"*

Here is a screenshot where the [SVG is just cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7Qxw.png). But others with the same specifications are fine. Sometimes on a page reload it renders fine too, but then again it doesn't render properly. (Remember, this only applies to Chrome. Firefox always renders the full icon, but not the gradients.)

**EDIT:** I should probably add, that both *width* and *height* of each icon is set to 100% in css so that it fits the container.

Somebody here has any solution for this or an idea why Chrome is handling this in such a strange way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please create a [mcve] and add it to the question.

Comment: Added some more information and a Pen. Hope this helps clarify my situation.

Comment: Your definitions are nested very strangely. All symbols and gradients should be defined in a flat list within a defs block. You have a gradient nested inside a defs nested inside a symbol. I'm guessing this is confusing Chrome. Also display=none removes an element (and all its contents) from the DOM - so Firefox correctly does not show a gradient when you hide the parent.

Comment: Linear gradients don't function in Firefox if either of the following are true a) they are within symbol elements or b) they are display: none. In your case you have both of these issues.

Comment: Ok, thanks to this I now fixed the gradients for Firefox. Now my only problem is that Chrome doesn't render some of the Icons correctly when display:none is not set. Could this be related to the specified viewBox? I mean the parent SVG Element has the correct width and height, only the use element is too small. EDIT: I just don't understand how one attribute changes how Chrome is handling the symbol in such a way :/

Comment: Alright, the problem Chrome had was caused by that already mentioned strange nesting. I just went over some of the SVG files that were given to me and cleared them up, and now it's working. Thanks for the help :)